# Focus, ao iniciar a página

Tags: html, input

Qual a melhor forma de fazer com que um elemento receba o foco assim que a página carregar

Comment: Você pode fazer isso diretamente no html com o autofocus

Comment: mas tem que ser automático, quando a page caregar

Comment: Sim, sempre que acessar a pagina ele vai ficar com foco

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode usar um recurso do html chamado `autofocus`

```html
<input autofocus type="text" name="Com Foco" placeholder="Com foco">

<input type="text" name"Sem foco" placeholder="Sem foco">
```

Comment: [Esse comportamente nao é suportado em todos os browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus).

Comment: @BrunoCosta 80% é uma boa margem, você não acha? Ainda mais considerando que os não-suportados são Opera Mini (alguém usa isso?) e o Safari pra iOS (ok, esse tem bastante gente que usa).

Comment: @jbueno O que eu acho é que os browsers deviam de fazer o esforco para suportar todas as funcionalidades para nós nao andarmos preocupados com estas coisas. Se voce ver de outra forma 1 em cada 5 pessoas nao vai ter o comportamento desejado.